# Display more than one video

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display multiple videos. The videos are stored in a blob, but anytime i run the code it only display the first video from the blob where the videos are stored. Could anyone help me with this issue.

```
<div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="_video" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="VideoDisplayControl" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <video width="320" height="240" controls=""> 
                    <source ID="videoDisplay" src='<%# Eval("Url") %>' type="video/mp4">  
                    </video>
                    <asp:Literal ID="label" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="20000" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

This method is the code behind rendering. The videogenerator is the name of the blob folder that contains the vidoes.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            VideoDisplayControl.DataSource = from o in GetVideoGalleryContainer().GetDirectoryReference("videogenerator").ListBlobs()
                                                 select new { Url = o.Uri };

            VideoDisplayControl.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `GetVideoGalleryContainer().GetDirectoryReference("videogenerator").ListBlobs()` return multiple results? Have you set a breakpoint to verify the size of the returned result? We can't see that code, so we don't know whether it's correct or not.

Comment: It return only one results

Comment: ok then so the problem is not in any of the code you have given. You need to give the rest of the code so that someone can help. Probably the issue is in the `ListBlobs()` function.